# Why is there such disparity between the calories in a banana and the calories in this pack of dried banana?

Tags: nutrient-composition, bananas, calories

If I Google

> calories in banana

I get the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgRIi.png) of 89 per 100g.

However, [this pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUG9j.jpg) of chewy banana
[says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67pg5.jpg) 320 per 100g.

Why the difference? The ingredients are

> Dried Banana, Rice Flour, Preservative (Sulphur Dioxide)

Do rice flour (which I presume is to keep the pieces from sticking) and sulphur dioxide add 3.5x the energy to a pack of dried banana?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Most of the weight in fresh fruit is water, which has no calories.

When you dry the fruit, the remainder is concentrated, so there are more calories in a given volume or weight.

[Sulfur dioxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_dioxide#As_a_preservative) is a preservative with anti-microbial properties.

The claim of 3.6 times the energy is specious.